# How to proper test appwidget?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-appwidget

I have an appwidget which is used as a button. I would like to thoroughly test it as it launches important activities for my application. How is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff, I would isolate the smarts that creates the `RemoteViews` in a separate method that can be called independently of the `AppWidgetProvider`, just using a `Context`. Then, you can test the generated RemoteViews using an `AndroidTestCase`.